# what is the way to work with gsvideo or qtvideo event handler in quil?

Tags: clojure, event-handling, quil

I am struggling with porting this code to quil wiht no success:

using qtvideo

```
void movieEvent(Movie m) {
m.read();
}
```

or gsvideo

```
void movieEvent(GSMovie movie) {
  movie.read();
}
```

I've done a lot of searchs related with this problem but no results :(

I suppose that the problem is to connect the (other) applet events to defsketch definition but ... i can achieve that simple thing

Can any one help me?
Thaks in advance!
Juan

EDITED: my clj file

```
(ns talendar.core
  (:use quil.core)
  (:import [javax.swing JFileChooser]
           [codeanticode.gsvideo GSMovie]))

(declare example movie)

(defn setup []
  (def movie (GSMovie. example "./data/station.mov"))
  (.loop movie ))

(defn draw []
  (comment "this way works but i'll prefer to work with event handler"
           (when (.available movie)
             (.read movie)))
  (image movie 100 100))

(defn movieEvent [e]
  (println "listen movie event!")
  (.read movie))

(defsketch example
  :title "j"
  :setup setup
  :draw draw
  :size [300 300]
  :movie-event movieEvent)
```

Comment: Where is your Clojure attempt?

Comment: @Chiron I just added it

Comment: note that quil depends on processing 1.5.1, it's probably best to upgrade quil to 2.0 and use built-in video.Movie from processing.

Comment: @edbond can you provide an example of built-in video? Thanks a lot!